# Gsub to keep all but 1 character

Tags: gsub

I have been trying to substitute "." in my data with ":", and keeping the trailing 00's, but upon switching out the decimals, my trailing zeroes disappear. Is it possible to switch only the ".", while keeping everything else exactly the same? I have been using:

```
gsub("\\.", ":",df[,1])
```

Comment: You probably need to store your column `as.character` instead of numeric/integer.

Comment: Well, storing the column as.character removes the trailing 00's. If I were creating the data from scratch that would be a method, but as this column already comes as.numeric, I'm not quite sure how to proceed from there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `format` to convert the string to character first:

```
gsub("\\.",":",format(df[ ,1]))
```

Comment: Yep, that handled it. Thanks!